# Show that $\int _E f=0$ whenever $m(E)<\infty$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

This question was asked in my exam yesterday and this is what I did.Will I get marks here?

> Let $ f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a bounded Lebesgue measurable function such that $\int_a^b f =0$ for all real $a,b.$
>
> Show that $\int _E f=0$ for each subset $E $ of $\mathbb R $ of finite Lebesgue
> measure.

Since $m(E)<\infty$ so given $\epsilon>0$ there exists an open set $O\supseteq E$ such that $m(E)-m(O)<\epsilon.$
Now $E$ is measurable $\implies m(E\setminus O)<\epsilon$.

Also $O$ can be expressed as disjoint union of open intervals $O=\cup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n,b_n)$.

By Dominated Convergence Theorem, $\int _O f=\sum _{n=1}^\infty \int_{(a_n,b_n)} f$ and hence $\int _O f=0$

Hence $\int _O f=\int _E f+\int _{E\setminus O} f\implies \int _E f=0$
since $m(E\setminus O)=0$.

Please check my proof.

Comment: Why do you say $m(E\setminus O)=0$?

Comment: Because $m(E\setminus O)<\epsilon $ for all $\epsilon>0$

Comment: But $O$ depends on $\epsilon$ so we can't take $\epsilon$ arbitrarily.

Comment: Will you please do the correct one?

Comment: Another issue is that you (correctly) write that $O\supset E$ and then suddenly you consider $E\setminus O$ (which is empty) and $m(E)-m(O)$ which is negative.